# SQLAlchemy - maximum column length

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

is it possible in SQLAlchemy to enforce maximum string length of value assigned to mapped column? All I want is to raise an exception if an assigned string value is longer then the length of the corresponding table column of type STRING.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to define the table and the mapping to your class.  AFAIK, the database should raise an error that propagates back through SQLAlchemy.  Please post code to provide some hint as to what you're trying now.

Comment: @S.Lott MySQL does not check string length on insert/update. It silently truncates strings that are too long.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easiest to just rename the mapped column and proxy it through a property:

```
class Something(Base):
    ...
    _foo = Column('foo', String(123))

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        if len(value) > _foo.type.length:
            raise Exception("Value too long")
        self._foo = value
```

You can easily factor out the property creation, and even use a generic validation framework like formencode.

---

If you need a more SQLAlchemy specific solution and don't mind using specific interfaces, then SQLAlchemy has an extension mechanism for capturing events on attributes. A validator using that would look something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import AttributeExtension, InstrumentationManager
from sqlalchemy.orm import ColumnProperty

class InstallValidatorListeners(InstrumentationManager):
    def post_configure_attribute(self, class_, key, inst):
        """Add validators for any attributes that can be validated."""
        prop = inst.prop
        # Only interested in simple columns, not relations
        if isinstance(prop, ColumnProperty) and len(prop.columns) == 1:
            col = prop.columns[0]
            # if we have string column with a length, install a length validator
            if isinstance(col.type, String) and col.type.length:
                inst.impl.extensions.insert(0, LengthValidator(col.type.length))

class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass

class LengthValidator(AttributeExtension):
    def __init__(self, max_length):
        self.max_length = max_length

    def set(self, state, value, oldvalue, initiator):
        if len(value) > self.max_length:
            raise ValidationError("Length %d exceeds allowed %d" %
                                (len(value), self.max_length))
        return value
```

You would then use this extension by setting `__sa_instrumentation_manager__ = InstallValidatorListeners` on any class you want validated. You can also just set it on the Base class if you want it to apply to all classes derived from it.

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem, but I have tens of such columns, so using the property is not very convenient. The solution which uses the SQLAlchemy type system would be better.

Comment: I added an example that can be used for sqlalchemy specific validators.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version that fits the event system of newer sqlalchemy versions:

```
class InstallValidatorListeners(InstrumentationManager):
    def post_configure_attribute(self, class_, key, inst):
        """Add validators for any attributes that can be validated."""
        prop = inst.prop
        # Only interested in simple columns, not relations
        if isinstance(prop, ColumnProperty) and len(prop.columns) == 1:
            col = prop.columns[0]
            if isinstance(col.type, String) and col.type.length:
                sqlalchemy.event.listen(
                    getattr(class_, key), 'set', LengthValidator(col.type.length), retval=True)


class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass


class LengthValidator(AttributeExtension):
    def __init__(self, max_length):
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __call__(self, state, value, oldvalue, initiator):
        if len(value) > self.max_length:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Length %d exceeds allowed %d" % (len(value), self.max_length))
        return value
```

Comment: I am not sure, it was around at the time of the original question, but would it nowadays not be easier to use the [validates() decorator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators)?