# SQLAlchemy 0.7 - maximum column length

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy maximum column length recipe from my previous question ([SQLAlchemy - maximum column length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317081/sqlalchemy-maximum-column-length)). Since I upgraded to SQLAlchemy 0.7, the `LengthValidator` cannot be installed using the following expression:

```
inst.impl.extensions.insert(0, LengthValidator(col.type.length))
```

The `extension` attribute is not defined in SQLAchemy 0.7. Is there any way how to change the recipe to work with 0.7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is Ants' solution rewritten with event system of SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import ColumnProperty
from sqlalchemy import event

def check_string_length(cls, key, inst):
    prop = inst.prop
    # Only interested in simple columns, not relations
    if isinstance(prop, ColumnProperty) and len(prop.columns) == 1:
        col = prop.columns[0]
        # if we have string column with a length, install a length validator
        if isinstance(col.type, String) and col.type.length:
            max_length = col.type.length
            def set_(instance, value, oldvalue, initiator):
                if len(value)>max_length:
                    raise ValueError("Length %d exceeds allowed %d" % \
                                            (len(value), max_length))
            event.listen(inst, 'set', set_)

Base = declarative_base()

event.listen(Base, 'attribute_instrument', check_string_length)
```

Comment: @zzzeek It's just a compilation of Ants' answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317081/sqlalchemy-maximum-column-length/2317843#2317843 and examples/custom_attributes/listen_for_events.py

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sqlalchemy.orm.validates decorator](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#simple-validators):

```
@validates('name')
def validate_name(self, key, name):
    assert len(name) <= 50
    return name
```

Comment: This way you have to install validator for each column while the original solution author refer to handles all String columns (except some rare cases like inline composites) without additional effort.