# Prevent SQLAlchemy from automatically setting IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a SQL Server table with an auto-incrementing primary key that I am manipulating using SQLAlchemy.  If I create an instance of that table's model that includes the primary key instead of leaving it off and call `session.add(instance)`, SQLAlchemy automatically issues `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table] ON` to the database and the insert succeeds.

Is there a way to control this myself instead?  I'd rather get an error if I try to insert a specific primary key instead of letting it be auto-incremented.  If I really need to set the primary key, I'd rather have to explicitly tell it so.

Here's the model:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Tub(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Tub'

    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    tare_weight = Column('TareWeight', Float(53), nullable=False)
```

Here's an example insert:

```
t = Tub(id=20, tare_weight=200)
session.add(t)
session.commit()
```

Here is the resulting SQL:

```
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Tub] ON
INSERT INTO [Tub] ([ID], [TareWeight]) VALUES (20, 200)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Tub] OFF
COMMIT
```

**Update:**

Another relevant situation I've realized is this:

```
t = Tub(id=20, tare_weight=200)
session.merge(t)
session.commit()
```

If the tub already exists in the database, I want its weight to be updated.  If it doesn't, I want the insertion to fail since it includes an explicit primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a long shot you could go full monkey patching. I'm don't think it solves all your problems, but it does prevent the use of `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`. You could monkey patch `MSExecutionContext`s [`pre_exec`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/43e0d7c06ba154e806a72d72ad06ae56a32225aa/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py#L1432)and [`post_exec`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/43e0d7c06ba154e806a72d72ad06ae56a32225aa/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py#L1488). For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base import MSExecutionContext

def pre_exec(self):
    if self.isinsert:
        tbl = self.compiled.statement.table
        seq_column = tbl._autoincrement_column
        insert_has_sequence = seq_column is not None

        self._select_lastrowid = (
            not self.compiled.inline
            and insert_has_sequence
            and not self.compiled.returning
            and not self._enable_identity_insert
            and not self.executemany
        )


def post_exec(self):
    conn = self.root_connection
    if self._select_lastrowid:
        if self.dialect.use_scope_identity:
            conn._cursor_execute(
                self.cursor,
                "SELECT scope_identity() AS lastrowid",
                (),
                self,
            )
        else:
            conn._cursor_execute(
                self.cursor, "SELECT @@identity AS lastrowid", (), self
            )
        # fetchall() ensures the cursor is consumed without closing it
        row = self.cursor.fetchall()[0]
        self._lastrowid = int(row[0])

    if (
        self.isinsert or self.isupdate or self.isdelete
    ) and self.compiled.returning:
        self._result_proxy = engine.FullyBufferedResultProxy(self)


MSExecutionContext.pre_exec = pre_exec
MSExecutionContext.post_exec = post_exec
```

My crude example of this in use monkey patches the functions that utilize the `_enable_identity_insert` functionality, and remove those parts. Now every attempt at specifically `INSERT`ing a ID will give you the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tub' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (544) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Your problem now will probably be that you are completely reliant on the auto increment functionality, but maybe it'll be useful to some, or you find some other way to bend around this functionality.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome/intense.  I tried it out and it worked correctly for both `add()` and `merge()` for a table with `__table_args__ = {'implicit_returning': False}`.  However, out of curiosity, I disabled the table's triggers and removed that table args line, and it stopped working.  Now, on the line `self._result_proxy = engine.FullyBufferedResultProxy(self)`, I get `AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'FullyBufferedResultProxy'`.  Also, what's with the use of `@@identity` instead of `OUTPUT`?  Isn't that dangerous?

Comment: To clarify, I tested both adds and merges that should either succeed or fail.  With `implicit_returning=False`, all four scenarios work correctly.  With `implicit_returning=True`, all but one of the scenarios still works.  The one that results in the error is an add that is expected to succeed due to it not involving an explicit primary key: `session.add(Tub(tare_weight=100)); session.commit()`.

Comment: @MarredCheese Ah, I see. It needs `from sqlalchemy import engine`, so maybe alias it to avoid collision with existing `engine`. How does that work for you?

Comment: Adding `from sqlalchemy import engine` worked.  Nice job.  I'll accept this answer since I doubt anything simpler will be posted.  I was really hoping there would be some simple configuration option to control this behavior instead of needing to monkey-patch core functionality.  It just seems so obviously wrong to me for the default behavior to consist of silently overriding a database rule.

Answer (score 7):

As per [SQLAlchemy 1.3 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html):

> For the case where this default generation of `IDENTITY` is not desired, specify `False` for the `Column.autoincrement` flag, on the first integer primary key column:
>
> ```cs
> m = MetaData()
> t = Table('t', m,
>         Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
>         Column('x', Integer))
> m.create_all(engine)
> ```

Comment: I do want the column to be auto-incrementing though, and that's how I've defined it in my database.  The problem is when I accidentally include a value for the primary key column, SQLAlchemy automatically overrides the column's identity property by calling `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`.  I don't like that automatic, silent override and would rather have it throw an error.

Comment: It's bizarre that SQLAlchemy assumes that by default every `Integer` column with `primary_key=True` must be an `autoincrement` - that's absolutely _not_ a safe choice. 
 The fact that it can easily be checked against DB metadata to prove/disprove makes it even stranger.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just override the constructor?

```py
class Tub(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Tub'

    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    tare_weight = Column('TareWeight', Float(53), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, id=None, **kwargs):
        if id is not None:
            raise ValueError("Hey, don't pass in `id`!")
            # or you could even just ignore that it was passed in and issue a warning.
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

If you want the same to apply to a lot of classes, you could implement a mixin:

```py
import warnings

class AutoIncrMixin:
    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    def __init__(self, id=None, **kwargs):
        if id is not None:
            warnings.warn("supplied `id` value was ignored")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Tub(Base, AutoIncrMixin):
    tare_weight = ...
```

Comment: For completeness, this solution should also guard against creating the Tub with no id and then setting tub.id to something else afterward. But unfortunately, even with that enhancement, I don't think I can use this workaround because I do still need the ability to create Tubs with explicit id's. The use case is that I want to be able to update an existing Tub from the database via the steps: 1) feed JSON from a PUT/PATCH request to marshmallow-sqlalchemy to generate a Tub object, 2) set the id explicitly from the URL, 3) call `session.merge()` to update the corresponding Tub in the database.

Comment: And just like with `session.add()`, I don't want `session.merge()` to automatically override the database column's auto-incrementing characteristic to forcibly insert a Tub with an explicit id that isn't already present in the table.  I just want to say to SQLAlchemy, "Across the board, never automatically disable the auto-incrementing behavior to do an insert."

Comment: Though this answer isn't something I can use in my current application, I decided to +1 because it does still seem useful.  Regarding my comment that it should also forbid setting the primary key from outside of the constructor (e.g. `tub = Tub(...); tub.id = 5`), I was thinking wrapping the id column in a property might work, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317843/5405967.  If it did work, it should remove the need for a special constructor.  I didn't get so far as to try implementing it, but I figured I'd mention the idea for whoever ends up reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my own answer to elaborate on my comments to @SuperShoot's answer.  I think if you're going to do a workaround where you block the primary key from getting a value in the first place, you should do so via a **property** rather than a constructor:

```
class Tub(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Tub'

    __id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    tare_weight = Column('TareWeight', Float(53), nullable=False)

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id
```

This prevents you from doing both of these things, not just the first one:

```
tub = Tub(id=5, tare_weight=100)

or

tub = Tub(tare_weight=100)
tub.id = 5
```

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Doing this will stop explicit primary key inserts because `id` will never get a value.  The downside is that you can't create objects and then call `session.merge()` to issue `UPDATE` queries.

...except that Python lets you cheat if you really need to:

```
tub = Tub(_Tub__id=5, tare_weight=100)

or

tub = Tub(tare_weight=100)
tub._Tub__id = 5
```

Comment: Your comments about requiring this to work with merge are the exact reason why I didn't update my answer to include this pattern. Have you had a look through the event hooks to see if there is something that you can hook into there? I've been meaning to have a look but too busy.

Comment: @SuperShoot Yeah, I figured.  No worries.  (I guess it must have pinged you since I did @ before your name.  I didn't even realize that was a thing within answers - cool.)  As far as this identity insert problem goes, I decided to move on because it's not critical - just something that bewildered me.

Comment: No notification, just have a tab open with feed of tags that I watch. Glad you got it sorted to your satisfaction then. Curious, did you implement the monkey patch solution?

Comment: @SuperShoot With the monkey patch, it seems like the complexity/maintenance burden is unwarranted just to deal with something that irks me.  I'll probably just do this property thing for cases where I don't need to merge and do nothing otherwise.