# Flask SQL Alchemy try perform SET operation, when it is not needed

Tags: python, flask, sql-server-2005, flask-sqlalchemy, sql-insert

I am facing a very strange issue using SQL Alchemy. I have a table in SQL server, to store Sales, with this format :

```
CREATE TABLE Resale (
  [address] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  [id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
  [price] INT NOT NULL,
  [start_date] DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL  DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
  [sys_start_time] DATETIME2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL,
  [sys_end_time] DATETIME2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL,
  PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([sys_start_time], [sys_end_time]),
  CONSTRAINT [PK_ReSale] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC))
  WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE=[dbo].[ResaleHistory], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=ON));
```

in python I used flask-sqlalchemy and build this model :

```
class Resale(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Resale'
    address = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())
```

now I am just trying to insert a record in this table using :

```
resale = Resale(address=address, id=id, price=price)
db.session.add(resale)
db.session.commit()
```

and flask return :

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Table 'Resale' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation. (8106) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Resale] ON]
```

I really don't understand why I have that, I am not using an autoincrement in my table, so my flask wants me to do "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Resale ON ?

honnestly I am completly lost with this message, I am just trying to add a record in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this answer for a previous similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742016/2532695) you should consider put the flag "autoincrement " to False on your "id".