# Unable to insert a row in SQL Server table using Python SQLAlchemy (PK not set as IDENTITY)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, orm, pyodbc

Have this Python Flask SQLAlchemy app that fetch data from a third party SQL Server database.
There is a table with to columns that I need to insert rows:

```
TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Desc] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ...
```

The primary key is not set as `IDENTITY`

Using SQLAlchemy ORM, if I try to add a new row without an explicit value for Id field, I have this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] ...
> The column not allow Null values* **(translated text)**

If I explicit an Id value, another error occurs:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] ...*
> *It is not possible to find the object "dbo.TableName", because it not exists or you don't have permissions* **(translated text)**

This error is followed by the sentence:

```
[SQL: SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[TableName] ON]
```

I'm supposing SQLAlchemy is trying to execute this command, but as Id is not set as IDENTITY, there's no need for that.

Using SQL Server Management Studio, with the same user of pyodbc connection, I'm able to insert new records, choosing whatever value for Id.

I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` will fail because a value *must* be defined for the primary key column of a table, either explicitly in your `INSERT` or implicitly by way of an `IDENTITY` property.

This requirement is due to the nature of primary keys and cannot be subverted. Further, you are unable to insert a NULL because the table definition explicitly disallows NULLs in that column.

You must provide a value in your `INSERT` statement explicitly due to the combination of design factors present.

Based on the documentation ([https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/dialects/mssql.html#:~:text=The%20SQLAlchemy%20dialect%20will%20detect%20when%20an%20INSERT,OFF%20subsequent%20to%20the%20execution.%20Given%20this%20example%3A](https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/dialects/mssql.html#:%7E:text=The%20SQLAlchemy%20dialect%20will%20detect%20when%20an%20INSERT,OFF%20subsequent%20to%20the%20execution.%20Given%20this%20example%3A)), it appears that SqlAlchemy may be assuming that column is an `IDENTITY` and is attempting to toggle `IDENTITY_INSERT` to on. As it is not an identity column, it is encountering an exception.

In your table metadata, check that you have `autoincrement=False` set for the `Id` column.

Edit to add: According to comments in an answer on a related question ([Prevent SQLAlchemy from automatically setting IDENTITY_INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57740618/prevent-sqlalchemy-from-automatically-setting-identity-insert)), it appears that SqlAlchemy assumes all integer-valued primary keys to be identity, auto-incrementing as well - meaning that you need to explicitly override that assumption as described here.